# Get the modified files names in between a push and pull from github

Tags: git, github

In locally we can get the modified files names between 2 commits by the following,

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~10 HEAD~5
```

I am trying to get the names of modified files between a push to github and pull. 
so for eg if i modified file A and pushed it to github and in another system i pulled it to my local repo i want to get the name as file A in my second system. How can we achieve this?

Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

You can call `git fetch` on the second machine, and then run `git diff --name-only master origin/master`. For each branch in a remote repository, git creates a local branch with a `«REMOTE»/` prefix, where `«REMOTE»` defaults to `origin` when you clone a repository and don't explicit specify something other.

When you want to take those changes, you simply run `git merge origin/master`.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the "history" of your `pull` or `fetch` actions by looking at the reflog of the remote branch :

```
$ git reflog origin/master
e05806da9 refs/remotes/origin/master@{0}: fetch: fast-forward
aeddbfdfa refs/remotes/origin/master@{1}: fetch: fast-forward
3ab228137 refs/remotes/origin/master@{2}: pull: fast-forward
```

you can then view the between the last two states :

```
$ git diff --name-only aeddbfdfa e05806da9
```